# Android ListView only shows first item

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a ListView that is only showing one item. If I make the ListView a set height, I can see that all the items are getting loaded into it, but the wrap_content is only showing the first row.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.fmsirvent.ParallaxEverywhere.PEWImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="370dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:contentDescription="@string/show_logo"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/hostGrid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/showDescription"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/showListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Update: screenshot

[image: The listView only displays the first item and cannot be scrolled]

Comment: Don't `wrap_content` for a `ListView`'s height. You can do `match_parent` there, and it'll just take up the rest of the space in the `LinearLayout`, since it's the last thing.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you want a ListView, RecyclerView, etc to take up all of the remaining space and perhaps have a minimum height. Since you've got yours in a LinearLayout, this will work nicely:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/showListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

If you find it's too small on some devices, you will need to put the LinearLayout into some sort of ScrollView and set a minimum height on the ListView.

To do that, you will need to use a [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html). The best way to achieve this will be something like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.fmsirvent.ParallaxEverywhere.PEWImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="370dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:contentDescription="@string/show_logo"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/hostGrid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:columnWidth="100dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/showDescription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/showListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the code you suggested but it didn't work. I thought you weren't supposed to put a ListView inside of a ScrollView

Comment: Check out [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html) which was made for this exact purpose. I've edited my answer with an example of its usage here.

Comment: Thanks for trying, still doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Comment: added above @DanielLaneDC

Comment: Could it have to do with the fact that it's in a fragment on the MainPage?

Comment: Being in a Fragment shouldn't cause a problem with this. Are you able to scroll the list view, it's just small?

Comment: Nope. I can't scroll the listview at all. If I make it a fixed height I can see other items but can't scroll at all